# Game decision design pattern

Tags: actionscript-3

So I have many objects with materials that each possess different properties (brick, glass, etc.) and are each affected differently by elemental effects.  A brick material for example will be affected differently by fire or acid than a cement material. A brick that's Burning or Melting will be affected differently when another Burning/Melting effect is applied.

At this point in my game, I have an FSM but it's very simple. If I drop a fire element on a brick, it would go to the Burning state. However if I then dropped a water element on the brick, I might want the fire to go out, take/add health and change textures (or not depending on the current combination).

The point is, I have many combinations with no commonality between them so I can't create something uniform. Sometimes I need to change the texture and other times I don't. Sometimes take damage while other times add health. Sometimes I need to just do nothing in a function. At this point, the only thing I can thing of is creating a global mapping such as:

FunctionMap[ObjectMaterial][CurrentObjectState][ElementBeingApplied]

(i.e.

FunctionMap[Brick][Burning][Acid]
FunctionMap[Brick][Melting][Acid]

)

The problem is, is that this is obviously a ton of functions due to the amount of combinations available with materials and effect types. Can anyone recommend a route to take or pattern to look at?

Although not entirely relevant to the discussion, this is being made in AS3 and Away3D.

Here are some of my classes for one example:

```
public class Brick extends AbstractBlock implements IFireable
{
    public function Brick()
    {
        super(this);
        this.material = new BitmapMaterial(_spriteManager.GetBlockMaterial(BlockUtilities.GetMaterialMap["brick_new"]));
        _type = "Brick";
        /*
        RulesManager.StateMap["Brick"]["OnFire"]["Water"] = some function;
        RulesManager.StateMap["Brick"]["OnFire"]["Fire"] = some function;
        RulesManager.StateMap["Brick"]["OnFire"]["Acid"] = some function;
        RulesManager.StateMap["Brick"]["OnFire"]["Ice"] = some function;
        RulesManager.StateMap["Brick"]["OnWater"]["Water"] = some function;
        //and so on...there are nine different materials so I'm not liking this way
        */
    }

    public override function render():void
    {
        super.render();
    }
}   


public class OnFire extends AbstractDamage
{       

    protected var _timeStart:Number = 0;

    private var _damageAccumulated:Number = 0;

    public function OnFire(block:AbstractBlock,bombType:String) 
    {       
        super(block,bombType);                                      
    }

    public override function enter():void        
    {       
        super.enter();  
    }

    public override function exit():void         
    {       
        super.exit();                                       
    }

    public override function update(time:Number):void
    {
        super.update(time);

        if(_timeStart == 0)
            _timeStart = time;

        var time_delta:Number = (time - _timeStart)/_waitTime;

        var damageToSubtract:Number = (time_delta * _damageDone);

        _damageAccumulated += damageToSubtract;

        _self.Integrity = _self.Integrity - _damageAccumulated;


    }
}
```

}

Thus, a fire element could be applied to a bunch of applies. One those blocks, currently frozen, is now hit and is now changing to the OnFire state. Each block has its own state machine and the states are themselves objects as you can see.

```
block.FSM.changeState(new OnFire(block));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your problem is that you have 9 * 5 * 4 combinations of effects, right?  Having separate functions for each of those would not be fun to manage.  But, even if it's a lot of data, you need it.  I would make that data as simple as possible, then parse it.  Something like:

```
var materialProperties = {
  brick: {
    fire: {
      normal: {damage: 10, image: 'brick_fire.jpg'},
    }
    water: {
      fire: {damage: 0, image: 'brick_smoking.jpg'}
    }
  },
  //... a lot more of this ...
}

class Material
{
  public var damage:int = 0;
  public var image:String = '';

  private var properties:Object;
  private var state:String;

  public function Material(properties)
  {
    this.properties = properties;
  }

  public function apply(effect:String):void
  {
    if(properties[effect])
    {
      if(properties[effect][state])
      {
        update(properties[effect][state]);
      }
      else if(properties[effect]['normal'])
      {
        update(properties[effect]['normal']);
      }
    }
    state = effect;
  }

  private function update(properties):void
  {
    damage += properties.damage;
    image = properties.image;
  }
}

var brick = new Material(materialProperties.brick);
brick.apply('fire');
brick.apply('water');
```

Comment: Not bad. I was thinking of a way not necessarily to condense the work of writing up the logic but rather the representation of such logic which is quite nicely implemented here. I'll keep the question up for another day or two but this is definitely an improvement. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have custom classes setup? To me, this sounds like an ideal solution.
Once you map out each classes properties and abilities, object management should be trivial.

ie a Brick class which has certain states [burning, melting] and reacts differently [function calls] when it interacts [collides] with another class [Water Class].

I hope I'm not barking up the wrong tree.... If you can provide a bit more on what your looking for, im sure someone smarter than me will jump in ;)

Comment: +1 this is a perfect example of when encapsulation should be applied. Let a Brick class handle everything related to that brick. Let the Bricks class handle all the Brick objects.

Comment: Yes I do. I'm editing my description above. The amount of spaghetti code and large amount of functions to create though would still be large.

Comment: You are forgetting states. If your Brick class retains the state "fire or whatever" then all you need is a function inside the class for each state. Then the class can determine what to do. And you really want to get slick then just have one function called statChange or something and just pass in the state. Then have the class determine the state to change to.

Comment: public var currentState:String; // FIRE,WATER,ICE,ACID

Comment: I could do that and considered it but it's still somewhat messy to me. What you mean is this right:

class Brick
{
function OnFire() {} 
}

Yea, I could do that but then I still have to do a bunch of checks in it for the conditions I mentioned. If this is what I have to do I guess that's okay but like anyone, I am curious if I could design this in a better way.

Comment: @Ilya I have been intrigued by this problem and I've got an idea I'm working out. I'll probably post something within 24h.

Comment: @Marc Nice, I'll be interested to see what you come up with.

Comment: @Ilya A few details I'd like to know. Regardless of material, you want to apply specific effects, correct? For instance, you want to be able to apply effects like DESTROY, HURT, HEAL, TILECHANGE based on the current STATE and the applied ELEMENT. Is my understanding correct? In regards to your question here, you are looking to be able to modify and re-work these effects (add more, etc.) without having to copy-paste or worse re-write a bunch of code. This is the problem you are trying to tackle, right?

Comment: @Marc - Correct. Another thing is, some of these states could have differing textures even if they are all of the same state. For example,. I could have varying textures for the burning state for types of materials or none at all. A brick, if it reaches an integrity of less than 80, would switch to texture "brick_heating" while if another fire element is applied to the same brick in the OnFire state, the integrity would be reduced to 20 maybe (still in OnFire) but now the texture switches to "brick_crispy")

Answer (score 1):

Short answer because I believe Mr Linquist does a great job of explaining it - but it sounds to me like a job for the [visitor pattern](http://johnlindquist.com/2010/09/21/patterncraft-visitor-pattern/).  In a nutshell, your elements (brick, concrete, etc) all allow visitors (fire, ice, acid, etc) to come and 'visit' them and apply their effects.

Hope this helps!